# Can we add one federation Id for multiple account names?

Tags: single-sign-on, federated-authentication

I have implement federated SSO in production instance. In our organization some of users have multiple salesforce accounts. Therefore I need to add one federationId for multiple user accounts? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly possible to use the same Federation ID for multiple User accounts in different Orgs. If a user has 2 different accounts in the same Org, then the same Federation Id can't be used for two accounts, since how would SSO know which one you wanted to log in to?

Comment: We just implemented that in our system. You can log into any sandbox or production with one login. Federated ID values copy as part of a refresh, so it minimizes work we need to do.